# Windows cmd command to list all files, folders and sub-folder with full path and owner name

Tags: windows, cmd

I am looking for Windows cmd command to list all files, folders and sub-folder with full path and owner name.

I have checked DIR /Q option which gives owner name but how to display that along with files or folder in following way ?

- C:\folder\file1.txt   user1
- C:\folder\file2.exe   user2
- C:\folder\file3.zip   user1
- C:\folder\file4.doc   user2
- C:\folder\file5.dll   user1

Comment: Please note that the Windows command line is not DOS.

Comment: Thanks  @TessellatingHeckler, but, this gives filename in owner in two different rows. what is need is both in same row

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thanks a lot, that's what exactly I was looking for. Since it is not possible without using powershell(using DIR etc), I will adapt my automation script accordingly by using powershell... thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving my PowerShell approach from the comment section to be an answer:

```
powershell -Command "gci c:\test -recurse |% { $_.fullname +' '+ $($_|get-acl|select -expand owner).Split('\')[1]}
```

Example output:

```
D:\t\a User
D:\t\b User
D:\t\a\aa User
D:\t\a\dd.txt User
D:\t\b\bb User
D:\t\b\cc.txt User
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy.

```
 dir /s /q
```

For more enhancement try

```
@echo off & for /f %a in ('dir /s /b') do echo %~fa %~za
```

Comment: 'dir /s /q' gives output in different format than what I described in question.      '@echo off & for /f %a in ('dir /s /b') do echo %~fa %~za' gives filepath sizeOfFile, but I need filepath owner